# Angular 5 Service httpClient Post - Title is not defined

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to post so data from an angular 5 service.

In the service I have:

export class DataService {
    title: 'My Title';

then

```
postIt() {
    return this.httpClient.post<any>('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', title: 'sometitle');
}
```

and then from my app.cmponent.ts onInit I have:

```
this.myDataService.postIt()
  .subscribe(
    res => {
      console.log(res);
    },
    err => {
      console.log("Error occured");
    }
  );
```

I'm getting error:

```
 ERROR ReferenceError: title is not defined
```

What I'm I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this :

```
postIt() {
    return this.httpClient.post<any>('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', { title: 'sometitle' });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Post request accept second parameter as a json body which is an object. When you try to send any data in post call, it should be in object format

```
const body = {name: 'Brad'};

http
.post('/api/developers/add', body)
 // See below - subscribe() is still necessary when using post().
.subscribe(...);
```

Below is the link for more details
    https://angular.io/guide/http